# How to display a bit of info about the link destination? Laravel

Tags: javascript, html

Probably not the best title, also, that why I ask here, describing this to a human may help me, describing it on google won't. I tried searching but I couldn't find.

How can I display some info about the destination of a link when hovering over it? For example if the link is towards a forum post I want to display a summary of the contents of the post, or if it is towards a site, display the site logo, title, a summary of the page? etc.

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with Laravel... well, Laravel could provide you with that info but the interaction that you're describing should be achieved with JavaScript/CSS on hovering an element.

Mock up those elements with HTML/CSS first, how they would look, and then use JS (or a JS library) to make it dynamic on certain actions (i.e: hover).

Comment: Not how to display it is the issue, how to get the information?

Answer (score 0):

Just use  an html tooltip attribute. Should be all you need.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Or if you need more complex elements just write js / jquery code for the class Onhover action